# How to convert JavaScript Array to elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have an `Array`

```
var fieldsToFetch = ['name', 'class', 'rollNumber'];
```

I am using this array into [NODE-ORM2](https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2) query, in simple words, I am saying to ORM that this are the fields I want to fetch.

```
Person.find({ surname: "Doe" }).limit(3).offset(2).only("name", "class", "rollNumber").run(function (err, people) {
    // returning only 'name', 'rollNumber' and 'class' properties
    //this is working fine
});
```

In this code, you can see the `.only()` function which takes the field names. If I am passing the name here by comma separating then it is working fine but if I do like this

```
Person.find({ surname: "Doe" }).limit(3).offset(2).only(fieldsToFetch).run(function (err, people) {
    // returning only 'name', 'class' and 'rollNumber' properties
    // not working 

});
```

I also tried

`String(fieldsToFetch );` and `fieldsToFetch .toString();` but it converts whole array into a single string. So how can I use this array as a parameter here?

Thankyou.

**EDIT**

Passing 2 or 3 parameter is not a challenge the main goal is to get all array element as individual elements.

Answer (score 1):

Because you pass an array, but it want separate strings, so if you use `ES6` you can pass like `.only(...fieldsToFetch)`.
This is called [**spread operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator). It gets the array, splits it into items and passes them as separate parameters.

Example

```js
function f(a,b,c){
  console.log(a);
  console.log(b);
  console.log(c);
}

var args = [1,2,3];

f(...args);
```

I pass the array with the `spread operator` and it splits the array into separate items and assigns to the parameters in direction from left to right.

Comment: but OP needs to put only two elements of array`.only("name", "class")`.

Comment: What does `...` mean? Is it a kind of operator or you want to say something else?

Comment: @ArpitMeena see the link, embedded in answer

Comment: @Suren _Srapyan thanks, but it is showing an error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...` and JSHINT is also showing an error: `[jshint] 'spread/rest operator' is only available in ES6 (use 'esversion: 6'). (W119)`

Comment: @ArpitMeena The spread operator needs `ES6`, but you use older version, you need to pass item by item like `.only(fieldsToFetch[0], fieldsToFetch[1])`

Comment: @Suren _Srapyan Can we write a function instead? or the function will again return the `array`?

Comment: You need to pass parameters one by one, spread operator was doing that,but in older than ES6, function will not help you

Comment: @Suren _Srapyan, the length of `Array` is dynamic it can be 5, 6 or 10 or anything. So what can I do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this..use `array.splice()` to remove last element from array.Then use `... spread operator`:

```
var fieldsToFetch = ['name', 'class', 'rollNumber'];

     fieldsToFetch.splice(2,1);//now array  having two elements ['name', 'class']
```

then

```
.only(...fieldsToFetch)
```